# Why is rpcbind opening a new and different port anytime it's restarted?

Tags: linux, udp, port, rpc

For my own sanity, does anyone know why rpcbind (linux) is opening a seemingly random port every time it's restarted? I know it uses port 111, but what is this other port that keeps opening up with it? Thanks.

```
    [root@testmachine ~]# nmap -sU -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1

    Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-03 16:00 EST
    Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
    Host is up (0.0000080s latency).
    Not shown: 65533 closed ports
    PORT    STATE         SERVICE
    111/udp open|filtered rpcbind
    819/udp open|filtered unknown

    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.11 seconds
    [root@testmachine ~]# service rpcbind restart
    Stopping rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
    Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
    [root@testmachine ~]# nmap -sU -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1

    Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-03 16:00 EST
    Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
    Host is up (0.0000080s latency).
    Not shown: 65533 closed ports
    PORT    STATE         SERVICE
    111/udp open|filtered rpcbind
    846/udp open|filtered unknown

    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.97 seconds
    [root@testmachine ~]# service rpcbind restart
    Stopping rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
    Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
    [root@testmachine ~]# nmap -sU -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1

    Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-03 16:05 EST
    Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
    Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
    Not shown: 65533 closed ports
    PORT    STATE         SERVICE
    111/udp open|filtered rpcbind
    892/udp open|filtered unknown

    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.86 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely, it's an RPC service. Try the [rpcinfo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man7/rpcinfo.7.html) command to see what it is.

Unlike most other network services (FTP, HTTP, SMTP, etc), RPC services are bound to dynamic ports. Instead of connecting directly to the server, an RPC client first sends a request to the RPC port mapper (UDP/111 by default) to find out what port the server is on (a similar is used on Windows).

On a related note, nmap is great, but there are much easier ways to learn about the listening ports on your computer. Try this instead: `sudo netstat -anp | grep LISTEN`. It's much faster and will even give you the process name and number.

Also, nmap 5.51 is about five years old now. If you use it often, it's worth upgrading to get some new features.

Comment: Thanks Archer. I didn't know nmap had a later version since I used yum install to get nmap. For what I need to do the 5.51 version is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian man page for rpcbind tells me that:

```
 All RPC servers must be restarted if rpcbind is restarted.
```

The OP didn't mention that they'd done that, so how would any of the RPC services have reregistered?  Imagine my surprise, then, on repeating the OP's experiment and applying the `rpcinfo -p` suggestion from @SArcher to see that all the RPC services were still registered... and on their original ports, suggesting that @SArcher wasn't quite on the money.

If, however, we also apply the other great suggestion from @SArcher, namely to `sudo netstat -anp`, we get something more interesting.  Now we can't `|grep LISTEN` as suggested because the OP's post says udp and UDP sockets are never in state LISTEN.  What we do find is that rpcbind doesn't just have sockets on port 111 - its job - but also another "reserved" port picked seemingly at random when rpcbind starts, just as the OP says.

So "what *is* this other port for?" you ask.  Sorry to tease but I just answered that in my description of:

[Debian bug 870579](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870579): rpcbind callit replies from a random reserved udp port, making firewalling hard

Answer (score 0):

On redhat there is a separate service called rpcbind.socket. This gets started with rpcbind.service. rpcbind.service first checks if port 111 is available, if it is not available then it chooses a port and starts listening on that port.
In redhat the rpcbind.socket is started first and it startes using port 111. In netstat the port 111 will be displayed as used by systemd. When rpcbind is started it finds that port 111 is already used by systemd and hence it chooses a different port. If you mask the rpcbind.socket service and then start rpcbind.service, rpcbind will start listening on port 111.